# Why don't App.config file doesn't get overwritten when the config is saved?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have this code to add some settings to the App.config in a WPF application. I thought it was a simple procedure, but in the end I couldn't save the setting to the file. Here is the code

```
 var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var settings = configFile.AppSettings.Settings;

settings.Add("server2", "http://someserver.com");    
 configFile.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
         ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(configFile.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
```

An here is the App.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="server1" value="someserver.net"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the application from visual studio will create a new vshost.config every time. And so the settings are empty again.

The code is correct and settings will also be saved in config file. 
Try running the `.exe` file from Debug/Release folder, the changes will be reflected.

Comment: Now I see, yes it does. So the next time it opens the config file, does it open the new created config file?

Comment: Yes.. vshost creates a new one everytime.